# WS_SYSMENU prevents window from resizing

Tags: c#, winforms

When I create a borderless window using these styles (and settings `FormBorderStyle` to `None`), I can resize the window in `WM_NCHITTEST`:

```cs
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams p = base.CreateParams;
        p.Style = WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE; // This works
        p.ExStyle = WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR | WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT | WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
        return p;
    }
}
```

But as soon as I include `WS_SYSMENU` in the window style, the resizing no longer works.

```cs
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams p = base.CreateParams;
        p.Style = WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU; // This doesn't :(
        p.ExStyle = WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR | WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT | WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
        return p;
    }
}
```

Oh and this is what my `WndProc` looks like:

```cs
const int _ = 4;
const int _t = 24;

Rectangle RectTop { get { return new Rectangle(0, 0, ClientSize.Width, _); } }
Rectangle RectLeft { get { return new Rectangle(0, 0, _, ClientSize.Height); } }
Rectangle RectBottom { get { return new Rectangle(0, ClientSize.Height - _, ClientSize.Width, _); } }
Rectangle RectRight { get { return new Rectangle(ClientSize.Width - _, 0, _, ClientSize.Height); } }

Rectangle RectTitleBar { get { return new Rectangle(_, _, Width - 2 * _, _t); } }
Rectangle RectIcon { get { return new Rectangle(_ + (_t / 2 - 8), _ + (_t / 2 - 8), 16, 16); } }

Rectangle RectTopLeft { get { return new Rectangle(0, 0, _, _); } }
Rectangle RectTopRight { get { return new Rectangle(ClientSize.Width - _, 0, _, _); } }
Rectangle RectBottomLeft { get { return new Rectangle(0, ClientSize.Height - _, _, _); } }
Rectangle RectBottomRight { get { return new Rectangle(ClientSize.Width - _, ClientSize.Height - _, _, _); } }

protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    base.WndProc(ref message);

    if (message.Msg == 0x84) // WM_NCHITTEST
    {
        var cursor = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

        if (CustomFormBorderStyle == FormBorderStyle.Sizable || CustomFormBorderStyle == FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow)
        {
            if (RectTopLeft.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOPLEFT;
            else if (RectTopRight.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOPRIGHT;
            else if (RectBottomLeft.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMLEFT;
            else if (RectBottomRight.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMRIGHT;

            else if (RectTop.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOP;
            else if (RectLeft.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTLEFT;
            else if (RectRight.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTRIGHT;
            else if (RectBottom.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOM;
        }

        if (RectTitleBar.Contains(cursor) && !RectIcon.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;
    }
}
```

Why is this? Is there any way to have a borderless window that has a system menu and is resizable at the same time.

Comment: `WS_SIZEBOX` maybe?

Comment: `WS_SYSMENU` requires `WS_CAPTION`. If you set both, but remove the frame (setting `FormBorderStyle = none` and commenting out your attempt to set the HT_*), you'll notice that you cannot resize the Window anyway: the `NCHITTEST`s are ignored. -- As a note, in CreateParams you're setting only default styles, you might as well remove it.

Comment: @Charlieface Using `WS_SIZEBOX` creates an ugly thin border around the window, which I don't want

Comment: @Jimi So is there no way `WS_SYSMENU` on a borderless window will still make `NCHITTEST`s work as usual?

Comment: I'm not sure you can *trick* the System, I've actually never used this combination. Maybe Hans knows. -- When I get to a Windows machine I'll test it.